# Alert if a docker container stops

Tags: prometheus, cadvisor

I'm monitoring several containers using Prometheus, cAdvisor and Prometheus Alertmanager. What I want is to get an alert if a container goes down for some reason. Problem is if a container dies there is no metrics collected by the cAdvisor. Any query returns 'no data' since there are no matches for the query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at Prometheus function **absent()**

> absent(v instant-vector) returns an empty vector if the vector passed to it has any elements and a 1-element vector with the value 1 if the vector passed to it has no elements.
>
> This is useful for alerting on when no time series exist for a given metric name and label combination.

examples:

`absent(nonexistent{job="myjob"}) => {job="myjob"}`
`absent(nonexistent{job="myjob",instance=~".*"}) => {job="myjob"}`
`absent(sum(nonexistent{job="myjob"})) => {}`

here is an example for an alert:

```
ALERT kibana_absent
  IF absent(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{com_docker_compose_service="kibana"})
  FOR 5s
  LABELS {
    severity="page"
  }
  ANNOTATIONS {
  SUMMARY= "Instance {{$labels.instance}} down",
  DESCRIPTION= "Instance= {{$labels.instance}}, Service/Job ={{$labels.job}} is down for more than 5 sec."
  }
```

Comment: What can i do if i have many containers and i do not want use hardcode in naming each container for this alert? Can you help?

Answer (score 3):

I use a small tool called [Docker Event Monitor](https://bitbucket.org/quaideman/dem) that runs as a container on the Docker host and sends out alerts to Slack, Discord or SparkPost if certain events are triggered. You can configure which events trigger alerts.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 time() - container_last_seen{label="whatever-label-you-have", job="myjob"} > 60
```

If a container cannot be seen for 60 seconds, it fires an alarm.
Or

```
absent(container_memory_usage_bytes{label="whatever-label-you-have", job="myjob"})
```

Please be careful, in second approach it may take time that memory usage by the container get to **0**.

Answer (score 0):

We can use those two :

`absent(container_start_time_seconds{name="my-container"})`

This specific metric which contains a timestamps seems not going stale during 5 minutes so it disappear from prometheus results as soon as it disappear from last scrape (see: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#staleness) and not after 5minutes like container_cpu_usage_seconds_total for instance. Tested OK, but I'm not sure if I understand well the slateness...

Else you can use this one :

`time() - timestamp(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{name="mycontainer"}) > 60 OR absent(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{name="mycontainer"})`

The first part gives how much time since the metric has been scraped. So this works if it disappeared from the exporter output but still returned by promql (during 5 minutes by default). You have to adapt the >60 with your scrape interval.

Answer (score 0):

[cadvisor](https://github.com/google/cadvisor/) exports `container_last_seen` metric, which shows the timestamp when the container was seen last time. See [these docs](https://github.com/google/cadvisor/blob/85796f19bf1986040f2b9644857fd46811b737f6/docs/storage/prometheus.md). But `cadvisor` stops exporting `container_last_seen` metric in a few minutes after the container stops - see [this issue](https://github.com/google/cadvisor/issues/2305) for details. So `time() - container_last_seen > 60` may miss stopped containers. This can be fixed by wrapping `container_last_seen` into [last_over_time()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#last_over_time) function. For example, the following query consistently returns containers, which have been stopped more than 60 seconds ago but less than 1 hour ago (see `1h` lookbehind window in square brackets):

```
time() - last_over_time(container_last_seen{container!=""}[1h]) > 60
```

This query can be simplified further when using [lag](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#lag) function from [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html):

```
lag(container_last_seen{container!=""}[1h]) > 1m
```

The `container!=""` filter is needed for filtering out artificial metrics for cgroups hierarchy - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69281327/why-container-memory-usage-is-doubled-in-cadvisor-metrics/69282328#69282328) for more details.