# Why is pod's memory almost double the pod's only container's memory with no ephemeral storage?

Tags: kubernetes, memory, kubernetes-container

Well, the title says it all :-)

I don't know where the extra pod's memory is coming from. Any command to reveal that? I want to set memory request correctly.

I look at it in Lens. I expect it to be the same in this setup.

Comment: Can you update the question to show the commands you are running to determine the pod memory, the container memory, etc?

Comment: As I wrote, I see it in Lens.

Comment: OK, I probably found an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69281327/why-container-memory-usage-is-doubled-in-cadvisor-metrics/69282328#69282328, I guess that's a Lens' bug.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I probably found an answer:

[Why container memory usage is doubled in cAdvisor metrics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69281327/why-container-memory-usage-is-doubled-in-cadvisor-metrics/69282328#69282328)

Lens probably just sum all metrics for a pod (= bug).